# Uber API token suddenly no longer working

Tags: uber-api

I don't know what happened but within the last day or two my Uber API token is no longer working.  My app hasn't changed in about 2 months and I have been using the same API keys for over 18 months now.  Has something changed with Uber's API?

Upon doing the following products call:
`https://api.uber.com/v1/products?cache_key=0.3082511832189301&latitude=27.8719024&longitude=-82.4946555`

I began getting this error:
`{message: "Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided.", code: "unauthorized"}`

Using AngluarJS, here is my code:

```
  var confHeaders = {'Pragma':'no-cache', Expires: -1, 'Cache-Control':'no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate', Authorization: 'Token ' +clientToken} ;
  var unique = Math.random() ;
  return  $http({url: "https://api.uber.com/v1/products" , cache:false,
    headers: confHeaders ,
    params: {cache_key:unique,latitude: startInfo.lat,longitude: startInfo.lon},
    timeout:httpTimeout
  }).then(function(response){ 
  ...
  });
```

Comment: In fact, I just tried to login to my Uber account via the Developer Dashboard and its not listing any apps associated with my account.  Its like it got deleted or something - but not by me, I haven't logged into the Dashboard in probably about a year.   What can I do?  Who can I reach out to?

Comment: Hello, 

Replied to you via email. Thanks.